# Why isnt my winner logic for my Rock paper scissors game not working

Tags: javascript

my game is able to get the users choice and the computers randomized choice. The problem is the decleration of the winner. Im using if statements to go through the choices of the player and the computer, but for some reason , the if statements wont return the outcome of the match in a innerHtml(i.e: winner.innerHtml = outcome of the match using the if statements). I've tried everything i could think of and the innerHtml value just isnt appearing.If possible could i get help to my problem without the use of any libraries or frameworks, just pure javascript? this is my code below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Rock, paper and scissors</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="assets/css/rockPaperscissors.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="assets/css/custom-bootstrap-margin-padding.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="assets/fontawesome/css/all.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>RPS GAME</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Welocme to the RPS game!</h1>
      <div class="text1">
        <h4>Instructions</h4>
        <p>
          Rock paper scissors is a hand game, usually played between two people,
          in which each player simultaneously forms one of three shapes with an
          outstretched hand. These shapes are "rock", "paper", and "scissors".
          In this game Rock beats scissors, paper beats rock and scissors beats
          paper!
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="text2">
        <h4>Minimum players</h4>
        <p>
          The minimum amount of players is 2, but the game can be played by a
          large amount of people and can even be arranged as a tournament!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text3">
        <h4>Rules</h4>
        <p>
          The players must throw their hands at the same time (preferably a 3
          second wait before the two players throw their signs.) and yell shoot
          the second they do so. When playing against the computer you will
          click a sign of your choice down below, (rock, paper or scissors.) and
          the computer will reply to your choice randomly. For every time you
          win you get 25 points. The game will be four rounds and the first
          player to get to 100 points wins the game. We hope you enjoy your
          gaming.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2>Choose your weapon</h2>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer-content">
          <div class="row icons">
            <ul class="social-links">
              <li>
                <a
                  ><i class="fas fa-hand-rock" id="Rock" onclick="rps()"></i
                ></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a
                  ><i class="fas fa-hand-paper" id="Paper" onclick="rps()"></i
                ></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a
                  ><i
                    class="fas fa-hand-scissors"
                    id="Scissors"
                    onclick="rps()"
                  ></i
                ></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <h1 class="wintxt">Result:</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <p class="comptxt">Computers choice is: <strong id="number"></strong></p>
      <p class="youctxt">Your choice is: <strong id="You"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <h2>Winner:<strong id="areWinner"></strong></h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //variables which store id's and querySelectors
      var computersText = document.getElementById("number");
      var yourText = document.getElementById("You");
      var winner = document.getElementById("areWinner");
      const icons = document.querySelectorAll("i");

      function rps() {
        //Computers choices logic
        var botChoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"][
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
        ];

        computersText.innerHTML = botChoice;
      }
      //Your choices logic
      let userChoice;
      icons.forEach((icons) =>
        icons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          userChoice = e.target.id;
          yourText.innerHTML = userChoice;
        })
      );

      if (botChoice === userChoice) {
        winner.innerHTML = "Its a tie";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Paper" && userChoice === "Scissors") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You won";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Scisors" && userChoice === "Rock") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You won";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Rock" && userChoice === "Paper") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You won";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Paper" && userChoice === "Rock") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You Lost";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Scisors" && userChoice === "Paper") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You Lost";
      }
      if (botChoice === "Rock" && userChoice === "Scissors") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You Lost";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stick a debugger statement just above your first "if". Does it get hit? If so, what values are in each variable?

Comment: Is there an error in your console? When does this script get run - before or after the DOM has loaded? What happens if you write `winner` to the console just before setting its innerHTML?

Comment: The logic seems to only run once. Not every time a user makes an input

Comment: I don't see where you call the `rps()` function.

Comment: You never actually set `botChoice`, and even if you did, you declare a new variable inside your `rps` function so `botChoice` wouldn't change the outer variable

Comment: Multiple typos: Scisors => Scissors

Comment: Can you please show us  the full code?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful input, i edited the code so you guys can all see things at a better angle.